# Angular app not working on Firefox and Safari

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My Angular app is not working in Firefox and Safari after build, But it is fine with Chrome

I tried by loading web animations in Polyfills and changed different polyfills versions

```
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/guide/browser-support
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
//import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 */
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
```

In Firefox the request goes to 301(Temparory re direct)

Comment: What do you mean with `updating the code to server`?

Comment: Also what do you mean "not working"?

Comment: Is your Firefox  cached? Make sure "Cached Web Content" is checked.

Comment: Could be `base href` not set in the `index.html`

Comment: @MauriceNino i just build the code from my local and updated to server

Comment: That still does not answer my question

Comment: @JeremyThille After hitting the URL i'm not getting home page, In Network it is showing  status code 301

Comment: Please send Content-Type:application/json in your request headers & check.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with Angular but rather your server not serving correctly